# UILabel byWordWrapping misbehaving

Tags: ios, swift, text, uilabel, word-wrap

Here is my code for my UILabel...

```
    var maximumLabelSize: CGSize = (chosenSpecies.identifyingCharacteristics![index] as NSString).sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16)])
    var identifyingCharacteristicsInformation = UILabel(frame: (CGRectMake(leftMargin, spacingValue, maximumLabelSize.width, maximumLabelSize.height))) 
    identifyingCharacteristicsInformation.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: informationTextSize)
    identifyingCharacteristicsInformation.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
    identifyingCharacteristicsInformation.text = chosenSpecies.identifyingCharacteristics![index]
    identifyingCharacteristicsInformation.text = identifyingCharacteristicsInformation.text!.capitalizedString
    identifyingCharacteristicsInformation.textColor=UIColor(red:0.0, green:0.0, blue:0.0, alpha:1)
    identifyingCharacteristicsInformation.numberOfLines = 0
    identifyingCharacteristicsInformation.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    identifyingCharacteristicsInformation.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = pictureContainer.frame.width                  
    ScrollView.addSubview(identifyingCharacteristicsInformation)
    spacingValue += identifyingCharacteristicsInformation.frame.height
    scrollView.contentSize.height += identifyingCharacteristicsInformation.frame.height
```

Here is what happens. Each one of these 'Characteristics' are printed using the code above in a for loop. As you can see, characteristics that are long run right off the screen.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvD5A.jpg

I have been scouring the web for reasons as to why this may be happening for several hours and have been coming up dry. Does anyone have any leads as to why this is occurring? I am having difficulties working with word wrap as my understanding is not throughout. I was able to apply it in other places within my code just by implementing these two lines.

```
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
```

Here is my attempted implementation of Eric Qian's suggestion. I am currently working through applying it.

```
var maxSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 320, height: 100)
var maximumLabelSize: CGRect = (chosenSpecies.identifyingCharacteristics![index] as NSString).boundingRectWithSize(maxSize, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16)], context: nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the width of the label. I believe it is over the screen bounds. You need to use

```
CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 1000.0);
CGSize maximumLabelSize = [string boundingRectWithSize:maxSize
                     options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                  attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16)} 
                     context:nil];
```

instead of `sizeWithAttributes` to get the correct size of the string. Since `sizeWithAttributes` renders the whole string in a single line.

Comment: I tried implementing this into my Swift code and get an error stating that     CGRect is not convertible to CGSize. I edited my post to contain my attempt.

Comment: I fixed that error and am currently attempting to implement your suggestion into my code.

Comment: It worked! So sizeWithAttributes returns a single line of text, not good for word wrapping UILabels as that defeats the purpose. Instead use boundingRectWithSize to get what size your UILabel frame should be when you create it :) ! Thank you!